# CakePHP 2: new exceptions

Tags: exception, cakephp-2.0

I'd like to create a new exception, called SecurityException.
Where should I put the code?

```
class SecurityException extends CakeException {};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590614/throwing-a-custom-503-exception-in-cakephp-2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an exceptions.php file, put it on the `Lib` folder and fill it up with all your `*Exception` classes. Then include it on your application's bootstrap file.

`require APP . 'Lib' . DS . 'exceptions.php';`

All exceptions will become available application wide.

Comment: [Here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cake-php/tK66NqCYMYw/6-FMj9XyvmYJ)'s another approach: "put exceptions in `([plugin-if-any])/Lib/Error/ 
Exception/NameOfTheException.php` and use `App::uses('NameOfTheException', 'Error/Exception')` where they're  needed. Seemed like a Cake'ish way to do it, and they're not  included unless one is actually thrown."

Comment: @luchomolina it should be an answer too. This is that awkward case when comment gathers more +ses, than the post :)

Answer (score 1):

I followed luchomolina's 2nd answer (commented on his own answer), and thought it deserved to be an official answer:

> Here's another approach: "put exceptions in ([plugin-if-any])/Lib/Error/Exception/NameOfTheException.php and use App::uses('NameOfTheException', 'Error/Exception') where they're needed. 
>   Seemed like a Cake'ish way to do it, and they're not included unless one is actually thrown." –luchomolina