# Throwing a custom 503 exception in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, exception, cakephp-2.0, http-status-code-503

I need to give a **503 Service Unavailable** HTTP header.

Normally I use these for 404 and 500 codes

```
throw new NotFoundException();
throw new InternalErrorException();
```

But I couldn't find relevant exception for 503 in CakePHP 2.2?

In my "app/lib/AppExceptionHandler.php" file I have this class/function that handles errors.

```
class AppExceptionHandler {
    public static function handle($error) {
     }
```

Edit:

- Inside "**app/Lib**" folder I created a file named "**MyExceptions.php**". I wrote the following code inside this file:

  ```
  class ServiceUnavailableException extends CakeException {

  protected $_messageTemplate = 'Service is not available now';

  }
  ```
- In "**bootstrap.php**" I wrote this:

  App::uses('MyExceptions', 'Lib');
- Then inside "**MyNewController.php**" file I wrote this:

  throw new ServiceUnavailableException("just trying");

But then I get this error when I throw this exception:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ServiceUnavailableException' not found in
 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/Controller/MyNewController.php
 on line 3560

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
(output started at 
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/Controller/MyNewController.php:3560)
[APP/Lib/AppExceptionHandler.php, line 19]
```

What do I miss?
Thank you

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690165/cakephp-2-new-exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Exceptions page in the Cake 2.0 book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#creating-your-own-application-exceptions) is worth a read.

Here's my short test:

```
// in bootstrap.php
require(APP . 'Lib' . DS . 'MyExceptions.php');


// in /Lib/MyExceptions.php
class ServiceUnavailableException extends CakeException {

    protected $_messageTemplate = 'Test';
}

// in controller
throw new ServiceUnavailableException('Service unavailable', 503);
```

Comment: Unless you need to customise ALL cake's exception handling, you probably don't need /Lib/AppExceptionHandler.php.  Also, the suggested App::uses() doesn't work for me, you could try require().

Answer (score 0):

http://api22.cakephp.org/class/cake-response#method-CakeResponsestatusCode

Will allow you to set a status code.

Comment: I'm trying to throw a custom exception for 503, because I throw default exceptions for other cases. Edited question.